# Chrome Extension context menu, differentiate image and link event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

In my chrome extension I'm adding two context items "Get link" and "Get Image". The main difference being when setting them both up they have the "context" of link and image respectively. But when right clicking on an image that is acting as a link you get the option of both:

[image]

when either of those are clicked the data that comes into the listener seems to be identical, I need to be able to differentiate the two to know if the context is that of an image or a link to handle them differently. Here is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "image";
  var title = "Copy Image";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});  
});
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "link";
  var title = "Copy link";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});  
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "imageAdded", subject: info.srcUrl}, function(response) {
});
```

Comment: Is the `menuItemId` property of the `info` object really the same in both cases? If so, which id is it: `contextimage` or contextlink`?

Comment: @apsillers Ah how'd I miss that! If you put that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @DasBeasto, looks like I misunderstood your question... I just thought you want to distinguish if users clicks same menu on different target (link/image), however, it seems you what you want is clicking different menu on the same target... Then I agree just `menuItemId` solved the problem.

Comment: @HaibaraAi yes sorry I suppose that was unclear, I just needed to know if the user asked for the Image or the link from that specific link-image element. Thanks for your answer though I appreciate it.

Comment: can you please share how did you copy the image link and image, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want know which menu item was clicked, you can get the `id` value of the clicked context menu item in the `menuItemId` property of the object passed into the `onClicked` handler:

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    console.log(info.menuItemId);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Parameter of onClicked callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create), you could differentiate the image/link via `mediaType`

> One of 'image', 'video', or 'audio' if the context menu was activated on one of these types of elements.

Comment: That would work for regular links. Unfortunately, if the link is an image the "Copy link" event still gives mediaType = "image".

Comment: @DasBeasto, could you please give me a sample link?